# Mocking Guice provided objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, amazon-dynamodb

I have an application specific module which is configure `DynamoDBMapper` and another class of application which relies on that mapper

```
public class ProjectAppServiceModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override protected void configure() {
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public AmazonDynamoDB getAmazonDynamoDBClient() {
    return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
            .build();
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public DynamoDBMapper getDynamoDBMapper() {
    return new DynamoDBMapper(getAmazonDynamoDBClient());
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public OrdersManager getOrdersManager() {
    return new OrdersManager(getDynamoDBMapper());
  }
```

}

Now, I want to do unit testing and in unit testing, I want to get a **mocked** object `OrderManager`.

I tried doing

```
@Mock
private DynamoDBMapper mockDynamoDBMapper;

Injector injector = createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(DynamoDBMapper.class).toInstance(mockDynamoDBMapper)
       bind(OrdersManager.class).toInstance(mockOrdersManager);
    }
});
```

and I got error that i can't instantiate with null objects. What would be better way to get around this problem? I guess to be approaching it wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the injector is created after the mock. Instead of using the `@Mock` annotation, I would create a method like:

```
@Before
public void before() {
    DynamoDBMapper mockDynamoDBMapper = mock(DynamoDBMapper.class);

    Injector injector = // ...
}
```